# Keeping data and formatting separate in object oriented design

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I am creating a program where I have objects called "hierarchies", which is little more than a list of lists with strings (`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`) with appropriate getters.

The user should be able to select the representation/formatting of these hierarchies - e.g. whether the hierarchy [1,2,3,4] should be represented as {1,2,3,4} or (1-4) or whatever, before it is written to a file.

Is there a clever/standard way to do this kind of separation of data and formatting? I am thinking of creating a "FormattedHierarchy"-object which merely consists of a Hierarchy-object and a Formatting-object, but I don't know if this is a good design choice or not.

Thanks for any pointers/tips/answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The worst thing you can do is coupling your hierarchy data representation with formatting. The hierarchy class should not know *anything* about formatting. My advice is to create a separate interface `HierarchyFormatter` with several different implementations.

I think code is worth thousand words:

```
public interface HierarchyFormatter {
    String format(Hierarchy hierarchy);
}

public class BraceFormatter implements HierarchyFormatter {
    public String format(Hierarchy hierarchy) {
        //...
    }
}

public class RangeFormatter implements HierarchyFormatter {
    public String format(Hierarchy hierarchy) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This is called a [strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). If some code needs to format your hierarchy, just pass an instance of `HierarchyFormatter` - any instance.

If you want to permanently bind hierarchy with some formatting, make your formatter stateful:

```
public abstract class HierarchyFormatter {
    protected final Hierarchy hierarchy;

    public HierarchyFormatter(Hierarchy hierarchy) {
        this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
    }

    public abstract String format();
}

public class BraceFormatter extends HierarchyFormatter {
    public String format() {
        //...
    }
}

public class RangeFormatter extends HierarchyFormatter {
    public String format() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Every time you create a formatter, you encapsulate the hierarchy class inside it.

Comment: "The worst thing you can do is coupling your hierarchy data representation with formatting. The hierarchy class should not know anything about formatting." - As I suspected, but did not know how to do this. But how do I connect the different formattings with the hierarchies? Up to me or what? I'll probably use a map if that is not a bad idea. Accepting this tentatively, someone will have to come up with something a lot better for this to change. Thanks !

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: obviously the formatter needs to know about hierarchy data, but not the other way around. I updated my answer to give you a hint how can you permanently bind some formatter with given hierarchy instance. Also you can use a simple ma from hierarchy -> formatter.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach it as a Model-View pattern.  Your *model* is the one containing the actual data: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and the *view* is the one doing the formatting, presenting the data in various ways. and that is the Formatting class.

Answer (score 1):

You could add methods similar to the standard `toString()` methods, e.g. `toArrayString()` to format the object as {1,2,3,4} or `toIntervalString()` to format it as (1-4) ...